# Android create fragment onCreate

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-toolbar

I am using navigation drawer with fragments.
Generally, I want the fragments to change the activity's toolbar title.

When starting the app, I supply a default fragment by using fragmentManager replace method.
But the fragment can't change the title of the activity's toolbar.

On the other hand, when changing fragments after App is started, it can change the activity's toolbar title

Can someone elaborate on this?

Thank you

Best regards Morten

Comment: Why you say that can not change title? You can easily

Comment: What is the problem with changing it? Just call getsupportactionbar.settitle

Comment: Seems the getSupportActionbar works. thanks you for quick response